# Check if adding an event listener is possible without adding one

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I want to add either a scroll event listener or a touchstart event listener. Initially I used the touch event to deactivate the scroll event listener as shown in the code below:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollStart, false);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);

function scrollMenu() {
    // do something
}

function touchStart(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollStart);
    // do something
}
```

But I realized that on some occasions, the scroll event is triggered as soon as the page loads. Therefore, I cannot use the aforementioned method. Is there another way to check if the browser supports a touch event listener without adding the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *should* be able to check whether the `ontouchstart` attribute exists in the `window`:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
} else {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollStart, false);
}
```

... I can't confirm the x-browser-ness of this though.

Comment: Wow, this looks promising. Let me test it out.

Answer (score 4):

Does Modernizr solve your problem? See example here for the various ways to detect touch events and each one's browser compatibility:

http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html

Comment: You should *really* include a summary of the detection methods mentioned in that link; what happens if the page goes down in the future? (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers))

Comment: There are many methods, do I need to implement all or is ontouchstart in window the only relevant one?

Comment: You should probably do a browser check and use the method most appropriate to that browser. If you are only supporting a single browser, use the one that works for that browser.